# A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:xjc: weblogic/utils/NestedException

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, maven-3, jaxb2-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</schemaDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
                        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have the above JAXB configuration in pom.xml. On building the code from cmd using the command : **mvn clean install ** I get below error :

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc (default) on project nm2m-core: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc: weblogic/utils/NestedException

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Additional information : I'm using jdk 1.6 and maven version 3.2.5